# Core Data - Fetch at most one instance of an entity where relation object is same

Tags: ios, core-data, swift2

[image: Data model image]

I'm developing a swift based application with core data. If you see the core data model, An activity could have many `ActivityFrequency` objects. I want to fetch at most one instance of `ActivityFrequency` where activity or activity.`id` is same. Previously I was using `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch the objects but after making some research I came to now that I could not do it by using `NSFetchedResultsController`. So I changed my code to this;

```
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ActivityFrequency", inManagedObjectContext: DBManager.managedObjectContext())
    fetchRequest.entity = entity

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(activity.goal.owner == %@ || ANY activity.goal.supporters == %@ || ANY activity.goal.participants == %@) AND (checkedInUsers.@count == 0 OR NOT (checkedInUsers contains %@)) AND (activity.startDate > %@) AND (checkInTime > %@) ", argumentArray: [currentUser, currentUser, currentUser, currentUser, NSDate().expiryDate(), today])
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "checkInTime", ascending: true)

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    fetchRequest.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
    fetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["activity"]

    var results:[[String:ActivityFrequency]]?


    // Execute the fetch
    do {
        results = try DBManager.managedObjectContext().executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as? [[String:ActivityFrequency]]
        print(results)

    } catch {
        let nserror = error as NSError
        assert(false, "Unresolved NSFetchRequest error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
    }
```

But its returning nil. I have made sure that the all the associations are set in the data and the same predicates are working great with NSFetchedResultsController except it doesn't show distinct results.

My questions;

1. Could I use NSFetchedResultsController to display at most one instance from all instances of `ActivityFrequency` related to same `GoalActivity`?
2. If not, what mistake I'm making in the above code?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have duplicates? Should you have duplicates? (In the data store, not in the fetch results) it's likely better to explain more about your data model and exactly what you want to display...

Comment: Thanks for spending your time on this @Wain. ActivityFrequency is basically an instance of the GoalActivity. A GoalActivity object can have many ActivityFrequency instances with different CheckInTime attributes. So technically ActivityFrequency instances are not duplicates (having unique identity in the DB) but I want to display at most one instance of all the ActivityFrequency objects related to one GoalActivity at a time.

Comment: How do you decide which one? Can you query the goals and take the first from the relationship? Can you add a new relationship, a to-one, which holds just the last one / one to display? Think about alternate approaches which will execute faster / more easily